# Delay the loading of a HTML video until played

Tags: jquery, html, video, load, html5-video

I have a div containing a video tag setup as such:

```
<div class="video-container">
    <video class="video" muted id="the-video"> 
        <source src="/templates/assets/video/v1.mp4"/> 
        <source src="/templates/assets/video/v1.ogv" type='video/ogg;'/> 
        <img src="/templates/assets/video/v1.jpg">
    </video>
</div>
```

The plan is that the video will be covered by an 'overlay div' which contains a link that when clicked, fades out the overlay and starts the video.

What I'd like to know is if I'm able to delay the initial load of the video until the link is clicked and the video is played, with the intention being to quicken page load time rather than loading the video before the page displays. This is my jQuery so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.play-video').click(function(e) {   
        $('.video-overlay').fadeOut('slow');      
        var video = $(".video").get(0);
        video.play();   
    $(".video").bind("ended", function() {
        $('.video-overlay').fadeIn('slow');
    });

}); 
});
</script>
```

What could be the best way to go about this? Should a larger video be used? Something which will impact load times?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems the answer/attribute I'm looking for is `preload="none"`. This stops the video loading when the page loads.

Just thought I'd put it out there in case anyone has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    loop="false"
    autostart="false"
```

Add this in you div video tag. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Well, I suppose what I'm looking for is like a lazy loading effect for the video, so the video only starts to load when someone presses play. If the video was quite large in size then it would surely affect page load times, hence the desired lazy load effect.

Comment: To be honest with you, I don't think there is such a thing.

Comment: Yes, that did cross my mind, but I thought I'd look into it in case somebody out there knew something I didn't with this